# XAML designer refuses to accept user control

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

The XAML designer either complains that the control isn't in the namespace or that the control can be placed in a UIElement Collection.

The control is defined as such:

```
namespace OdinSyncManager.Controls
{
    public partial class ServiceListItem: UserControl
    {
        public ServiceListItem()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

The XAML has the following code (I've only included the head of the file up to the control):

```
<...
    xmlns:Control="clr-namespace:OdinSyncManager.Controls"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow">
<DockPanel LastChildFill="True" Margin="0,0,14,14" Background="#FFFF6D6D">
    <Control:ServiceListItem/>
<...>
```

I'm not sure what's missing?

Comment: did you try to build?

Comment: @ShloimeRosenblum Yes, the Designer still says "invalid Markup". Although now the error message says "Expected type UIElement".

Comment: Make sure xmlns:Control="clr-namespace:OdinSyncManager.Controls" is a valid path. If the user control is inside a folder then you need to  make sure you are declaring the correct path to that user contro.

Comment: @Kishore I'm not sure how to check that beyond the fact that it says `namespace OdinSyncManager.Controls` right above the usercontrol declaration.The ServiceListItem.cs file is inside a "Controls" folder.

Comment: when you type control: does it show your UserControl?

Comment: @ShloimeRosenblum It does not.

Comment: can you post the xaml of your UseControl?

Comment: @ShloimeRosenblum There are two files associated with the control, a *.cs and a *.Designer.cs, there's no *.xaml file

Comment: in winforms it has a .Designer.cs but in wpf it must be a .xaml and a .xaml.cs

Comment: i think you added a winform item to your project by mistake

Comment: @ShloimeRosenblum Hah, it seems like I added a "User Control" to my project when I should have added a "User Control (WPF)". Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you added a WPF UserControl to your project, not a winform

Comment: adding this answer for anyone that may have this problem in the future